# AngularJS Calling a service not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a service from inside the function "onNotification(e, $scope, currentUser)" However every time I try and log it, it either comes back with the error:

> processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'Current' of undefined

or if I use "var userRegistration = this.currentUser" I get "undefined" in the log, however I know that the service is being updated as it returns the correct value when I log the result outside the function.

Here's my code:

```
function onNotification(e, $scope, currentUser) {
var Currentuser = this.currentUser;

$("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

switch( e.event )
{
case 'registered':
    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
    {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
        // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.

        console.log(Currentuser);

        console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
    }
break;

case 'message':
    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
    if ( e.foreground )
    {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

        // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
        // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
        var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);
        my_media.play();
    }
    else
    {  // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
        if ( e.coldstart )
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
        }
    }

   $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');

   $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
break;

case 'error':
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
break;

default:
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
break;
}
}
```

Here's the Service within the same js file:

```
App.service('currentUser', function () 
{   
return{};
});
```

How should I go about calling the service inside this function? My Angular knowledge is limited. Any help would be much appreciated.

*Update*: In response to user PSL. onNotification is called here:

```
App.controller('LogHomeCtrl', function($scope, $log, $state, currentUser)
{
var pushNotification;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{   
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
    if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android'){

        pushNotification.register(
        successHandler,
        errorHandler,
        {
            "senderID":"460885134680",
            "ecb":"onNotification"
        });
    } else {
        pushNotification.register(
        tokenHandler,
        errorHandler,
        {
            "badge":"true",
            "sound":"true",
            "alert":"true",
            "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
        });
    }
}

function successHandler (result)
{
    alert('result = ' + result);
}

function errorHandler (error)
{
    alert('error = ' + error);
}
});
```

Comment: What is `onNotification`? is it a controller or something ? How are you injecting something there ex how are you passing `$scope`?

Comment: onNotification is a function that sits outside of any controller (it doesn't work if I place it in a controller). and I am injecting it through the normal way(that has worked elsewhere) by placing the service name and $scope in the brackets after the function name "onNotification(e, $scope, currentUser)"

Comment: Can you show the place where you are calling `onNotification` ? What is `e` ? Is that a service name? You must be passing in $scope right

Comment: I dont know what this plugin is.. But try sending `currentUser` as key value pair just the way you are sending  `badge` `sound` etc..

Comment: the plugin in PushPlugin, it's for sending push notifications to apple and android devices. I have tried the method you suggested, to no avail (still coming back as undefined). Would it be an idea to somehow extract e.regid (the other value i need) and try and push that into an array and any idead how would I go about that?

Comment: Can you prepare a demo in a plunker?

Comment: the issue I have with doing that is that I have some functions linking to private IP addresses that I can't give out.

Comment: Just provide a [minimal example to replicate the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot accurately use the code because it needs to be run on a device for the plugin to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
var Currentuser = this.currentUser;
```

to

```
var Currentuser = currentUser;
```

`currentUser` does not belong to `onNotification` it is meerly being passed in as a parameter and therefore being defined as a variable in its local scope. But not as a property of itself

**Edit**

`onNotification` ought to be defined inside a controller. eg

```
yourModuleName.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', 'currentUser', function($scope, currentUser) {

   $scope.currentUser = currentUser;

   $scope.onNotification = function(e, $scope, $scope.currentUser) {

   }

}]);
```

Comment: no it is still returning undefined. Could it have something to do with the fact that it is a service?

Comment: where is `onNotification` defined? is it inside a controller?

Comment: no, I have tried to place it in the same controller but it then tells me that onNotification is not defined.

Comment: Sorry for late reply needed to sleep. I have done as you said and it throws an error, if I use $scope.onNotification, it returns "$scope is not defined" and if i use function onNotification, I get onNotification is not defined.